# Setting cookies in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web application which creates two cookies at host pid and tid. The pid has a value created at host and tid has a value '0'.

My requirement is when the host calls the MVC Web API 2 server, it sends these cookies, if the tid value is '0', create a guid value for it and add the cookie expiry date a day later. If the tid cookie has value not equal to '0', just increase the cookie expiry date.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage check()
{
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    CookieHeaderValue cook = Request.Headers.GetCookies("tid").FirstOrDefault();
    if (cook["tid"].Value != "0")
    {
        var cooki = new CookieHeaderValue("tid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        cooki.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
        cooki.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cooki.Path = "/";
        resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cooki });
    }
    return resp;
}
```

The code above is sending a HTTP response message with a set cookie tid (when I check through the developer tools, I find that the response contains a cookie tid with values) but the cookie value of tid is not changing, so next time when I make the call the request message containing tid cookie value is again '0'.

Has anyone faced such a problem before? Any idea why something like this could happen?

Update: I also tried

```
if (cook["tid"].Value != "0")
{
    cook["tid"].Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    cook.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
    cook.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
    cook.Path = "/";
    resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cook });
}        
return resp;
```

Now what happens is even more surprising to me.
`cook["tid"].Value` gets a guid value.

But, when I check the values of cookies inside 'cook' the value of cookie(tid) does not change from '0' and the same thing I found in the response as well, which had the same pid and tid values which were sent.

Comment: Side note: using cookies in WebAPI requires cooperation from client. Usually API called by some AJAX code in browser or even non-browser code, so if client does not send cookies properly you'll never see any updated values. Browser's cookie management usually not getting involved into such code (except you may get extra cookies set by normal request and automatically attached by browser to requests on same domain).

Comment: The cookies are being sent as well as received , I can check them from developer tools, but the cookie value is not being updated..

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing your Web API call and step through if it's actually setting the GUID to the cookie?

Also, is it possible that the cookie only exists within the realm of the AJAX call, and not transmitted back into the SPA page (ie., the main page doesn't "re-absorb" the value?)

Comment: @Jason Yes the Guid is being set to the cookie, it is even coming back to the browser. I can chk that in the browser developer tools. Am I supposed to do something to ensure that the page absorbs the cookie.

Comment: @Arnab -- if it's in the response, and shows up as a set cookie in the Inspector tools (Chrome > F12 > Resources > Cookies) -- it's there, and should be able to be acted on.

Comment: As noone has mentioned this... if you are using cookies with web API it's a code smell... your API is likely not restful.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Restful is not a requirement of Web API.  Though it is frowned upon to not be restful for distributed endpoints.  If the Web API is only something your web app (alongside your MVC) is accessing, working with cookies isn't so bad.

Comment: JWT Cookies and JWT local storage are equally restful. Cookies aren't avoided because of the goal of statelessness, but because not every api consumer will support cookies.